# what's wrong in my cod? I am new in flask

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request

from datetime import datetime

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLACHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='mysql://root:password@localho st/sarwar_DB'

db=SQLAlchemy(app)

class Contact(db.Model):

    sno = db.column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.column(db.String(20),nullable=False)
    email = db.column(db.String(20),nullable=False)
    phone_no = db.column(db.String(20),nullable=False)
    msg= db.column(db.String(120),nullable=False)
    date = db.column(datetime)
@app.route("/")

def home():

    return render_template('index.html')
    
@app.route("/login")

def login():

    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route("/notice")

def notice():

    return render_template('notice.html')

@app.route("/contact",methods=['GET','POST']) 

def contact():

        if(request.method=='POST'):
            name=request.form.get('name')
            email=request.form.get('email')
            phone=request.form.get('phone')
            message=request.form.get('message')            
            entry = Contact(name=name, email=email, phone_num = 
            phone, msg = message, Date=datetime.now())

            db.session.add(entry)

            db.session.commit()

app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please review [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the contact route does not return anything.

To fix that, you could add `return "success"` to it.

Error messages etc. would be helpful tho...